# foreach-if-statment w/ Linq conditional giving unexpected results

Tags: c#, linq

This is a part of a Tic-Tac-Toe game.
the checkmate method returns a string that will be used by another fucntion (not shown here) to make a tic-tack-toe move.

Here is the board, the player has two pieces lined up on the top row:

```
public static char[] board = { '+', '+', 'E',
                               'A', 'S', 'D',
                               'Z', 'X', 'C' };
```

And here is the code that determines the next move:

```
private static string checkmate()
{      
    List<char[]> dalist = new List<char[]> 
    {
        new char[3] { board[3], board[4], board[5] },
        new char[3] { board[0], board[4], board[8] },
        new char[3] { board[2], board[4], board[6] },
        new char[3] { board[1], board[4], board[7] },

        new char[3] { board[0], board[1], board[2] },
        new char[3] { board[6], board[7], board[8] },
        new char[3] { board[0], board[3], board[6] },
        new char[3] { board[2], board[5], board[8] }
    };

    foreach (var item in dalist)
    {
        if (item.Where(x => x == '+').Count() == 2)
            return new string(item.Where(x => x != '+').ToArray());

        else if (item.Where(x => x == '-').Count() == 2)
            return new string(item.Where(x => x != '-').ToArray());

        else if (item.Where(x => x == '+').Count() == 1)
            return item.Where(x => x != '+').First().ToString();

        else
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int rList = random.Next(0, 3);
            int rPosition = random.Next(0, 2);
            return dalist.ElementAt(rList).GetValue(rPosition).ToString();
        }
    }
    return "AA";
}
```

The method returns a single letter as a string that corresponds to a move on the board.

The method analyses the board by creating a list of the 8 possible winning patterns in tic-tack-toe, and testing them against what is already on the board

the logic four components that are worked in order as ifelse conditionals in the foreach loop.
For the current the method should return 'E'    and breakout of the loop at the first if statement.  Instead the program goes through the whole loop and returns that final else statement?
**Why is it not identifying the match of the first if-condition?**

The loop should loop through each of the 8 list item until there is a match.

1) `checkmate` which will return the winning move if there is one available

2)  if there is not a checkmate move this move will check if opponent has a checkmate move and block the path

3)`link two` If there is not a checkmate to win or to block this will place a second piece to link in a winning path

4) *Place initial*  randomly on one of the four corners or middle for first two rounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform each individual test on all the possible wining moves. Not every test on the first winning move then every test on the second winning move, etc. So wrap a for loop around each test and leave the random block to run if none of the loops find a match.

Comment: yes, steped away from the computer and had an egg and came to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you think the first if statement should be true and thus the function should return. I guess you think the first `item` is `{'+' ,'+', 'E'}`.

But this is incorrect. The first `item` is `{'A', 'S', 'D'}` because when you created `dalist`, the first char array is `{ board[3], board[4], board[5] }`.

EDIT!

I see now that your function is guaranteed to return on the first iteration of the for-each loop, since every execution path has a return statement. So it will never reach the row with `{'+' ,'+', 'E'}`.

Comment: That was also my initial thought, but I think the first condition is never met, not even by the 5-th element in `dalist`

Comment: @MongZhu Ah, I see what you're saying. I'm not sure what the OP means to do here. It seems to me, that in the first loop of the foreach, the final else will execute, and the function will return. So it will never reach any other dalist items. Either way, all execution paths in the loop return from the function during the first iteration.

Comment: Eli, Im looking to check each List item against the first if-conditinal, so that it does not move to the second else-if statement until all 8 arrays in the list have been checked. and so on..

Comment: it should match on the fifth list item (index #4) and return the string 'E'    At least that's what I'm looking to do

Comment: @Aarondv1 i think Eli is right you never reach the fifth element because your loop ends after the first iteration